# YiiMail sending attachment

Tags: yii

In my Project i am using YiiMail extension to send mail to the users. in which i am attaching a file. but the problem is its not possible to send the mail using the attachment. my mail code is given below.

```
$this->email->setBody('<p>'.$email.'-'.$name.'-'.$details.'</p>', 'text/html');
$this->email->from = "test@test.com";
$this->email->setSubject('Direct Request');
$this->email->attach(CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileupload'));
$this->email->setTo(array($emailId => 'test@test.com'));
```

with this code the mail is not sending and error message is showing.
**Argument 1 passed to Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage::attach() must implement interface Swift_Mime_MimeEntity, instance of CUploadedFile given**

what is reason this error is showing and any solution for this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert your file attachment to a SwiftMailer `Swift_Mime_MimeEntity` type. `CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileupload')` returns a [CUploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CUploadedFile) class, which SwiftMailer does not know how to handle. More on [Swift attachments here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html).

I have not tested this, but you will need to do something like this:

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileupload'); // get the CUploadedFile
$uploadedFileName = $uploadedFile->tempName; // will be something like 'myfile.jpg'
$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); // create a Swift Attachment
$this->email->attach($swiftAttachment); // now attach the correct type
```

Good luck!